# Can I access the member of the struct only by the struct name?

Tags: c, memcached

```
struct settings {
    size_t maxbytes;
    int maxconns;
    int port;
    int udpport;
    int chunk_size;
};
```

Just as shown above, define a struct `settings`, and access the struct member like `settings.chunk_size`, I come across this usage in the memcached source code,is that OK? If true, what is the function?

Comment: That would be illegal. However you can have a variable with the same name as a struct tag. E.g. `struct settings settings; settings.chunk_size = 10;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the `structure member` with `structure name`. You have to declare a structure object for accessing.

```
struct settings {
    size_t maxbytes;
    int maxconns;
    int port;
    int udpport;
    int chunk_size;
};
```

struct settings p1; //`Declaring a structure variable`

Now you can access the members using the "." operator. (For example `p1.port`).

You can use the same name for tag and variable like `struct settings settings.`

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you are seeing is an object with the name `settings`. This is legal C:

```
struct settings settings;
settings.chunk_size = 1024; // Access the object, not the type.
```

In C++, the `struct` specifier is optional, so you could just as well see a variable declaration reading simply `settings settings;`.